# To delimit and isolate a quantic system ? A pure fiction ? Or not?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

An unreliable author wrote :
"*parameters that define uniquely the result of each trial and trial in
an experiment. For instance, assume that we work with the polarization
singlet. The power of prediction I expect from these parameters is not
to predict a result R1 with probability P1, a result R2 with
probability P2, etc., but to predict for the pair of particles in each
given trial, exactly the result.*"

So this author assumes that to delimit and isolate a quantic system is
a feasible operation. And by the way, that knowing **all** the initial
conditions is within reach.
I doubt very much on this assumption, but the majority seems in favor
of it, openly or secretly.

Against it :

1. The quantic fluctuations of the vacuum have been proved, at 1%
   for the Casimir effect.
2. The Dirac-de-Broglie permanent noise is unshieldible.
3. Due to the de Broglie and Dirac-Schrödinger frequencies involved
   in the Dirac-de-Broglie noise, the W.R. **Ashby's theorem of the
   requisite variety** is an unclimbible wall for knowing all the initial
   conditions for each trial. Though on the big numbers of trials, one may
   expect that the Dirac-de-Broglie noise will average itself and may be
   ignored in the statistics.

And the pro arguments ? Have you exemples of success in experiments,
with individual trials, individual predictions and individual successes ?

Notes :
In the frame of a massive particle of mass **m**, its Broglian intrinsic
frequency is **mc²/h**, and its Dirac-Schrödinger frequency is **2 mc²/h**. Of
course the Lorentz transform applies, for other frames.
The Dirac-Schrödinger frequency intervenes in all electromagnetic
interactions, by exemple in the Compton scattering.

Comment: It has already been proved by all variants of delayed choice
experiments, that the dream of an isolation of the emitter of two
correlated photons, is misleading. The emitter and the two absorbers
remain tied until the last absorption is done. So forward isolation and
delimitation do not exist.

What is new in my statement above, is that a lateral isolation and
delimitation do not exist either.